# client side validation for asp.net mvc dropdown?

Tags: validation, list, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

i just wanted to know how to enable client side validations for dropdowns in asp.net mvc 2.
The scenario would be that the dropdown will contain a "Select" item and the list of other items..,The user should select other items... the validation should fire when the user does not select the other items

```
public class FacilityBulletinModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Select a Facility")]
        public List<SelectListItem> ListFacility { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Facility Bulletin")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please create a Bulletin")]
        public string FacilityBulletin { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Active")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

       [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int SiteId { get;set;}
    }
```

in my view

```
 Select Facility <span class="err">*</span><br />
    <%=Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListFacility, null, new {onChange="updateSiteId()" })%>
   <span class="err"> <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ListFacility) %></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if a dropdown is required, add the [Required] attribute to your model property.

Then, enable client side validation somewhere at the top of your view:

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation() %>
```

Then just add a validation message:

```
<div class="inputField">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.property)%>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.property, (SelectList)ViewData["myselelectlist"])%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.property)%>
</div>
```

(this requries MicrosoftMvcValidation.js to be loaded)